Algorithm for Finding the Square Root of a Perfect Square
I am quite new to this forum. I am just wondering if anybody can help me determine why this algorithm works. I was playing around with small square numbers (greater than 100 but less than 10000) and I was trying to look for a quick way to determine their square roots. Of course I know the square roots because I solve for the squares first then try to calculate their square roots. For some reason, I can go back to the square roots of the squares using the following steps:
Suppose that the square is 4096.

Subtract a square from 4096 such that the difference is divisible by 10.
4096 - 16 (4 squared) = 4080

Divide the difference by 4.
4080/4 = 1020

Find the factors of 1020 such that the difference of the factors is the square root of the subtrahend from step 1.
34 x 30 = 1020; 34 - 30 = 4 (the square root of 16).

Add the factors from step 3. This is the square root.
34 + 30 = 64


64 x 64 = 4096
I have been playing with this  for quite some time though I do not know how it works. Somebody please help and explain.

If $b^2$ is the small square in 1 then the factorization has the form $c(c-b)$ and the square you started with has the form $2c-b$. So you need to search for $c$, which I guess is pretty much equivalent to finding the square root in the first place.

Perhaps something easier works in that range knowing the ten squares up to $10^2=100$: (a) the answer has two digits; (b) since $3600\le 4096<4900$ the first digit is $6$; (c) since $3600\le 4096<\frac{3600+4900}{2}$ the final digit is one of $0,1,2,3,4,5$; (d) the only one of those which squared has a final digit of $6$ is $4$; and thus the answer must be $64$.

The divisibility condition at step $1$ can be weakened.  All we need is a square such that the difference is even:

$4096 - 8^2 = 4032$ (even)
$4032 / 4 = 1008$ (if the step $1$ difference wasn't even, we could not do step $2$).
$1008 =  36 \cdot 28$ where $36  - 28 = 8$
$36 + 28 = 64$

The reason why divisibility by $10$ was chosen as the condition for step $2$ is probably because it makes finding the factors somewhat easier: the last digit of one of the factors will be either $0$ or $5$.

Let $a^2$ be your initial number. Let $b^2$ be the square you find at step $1$.

Your difference will be $d = a^2 - b^2  = (a+b)(a-b)$.
If it is even, then either $a-b$ or $a+b$ are divisible by $2$. But they are of the same parity, as their difference is $2b$.  So both $\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $\frac{a-b}{2}$ are integers.
So the quartered difference $\frac{d}{4} = \frac{a^2 - b^2}{4}$ can be factored as $(\frac{a+b}{2})(\frac{a-b}{2})$.  
But this is the only available factoring of of $\frac{d}{4}$ that has the difference of factors equal to $b$ (this can be proven). That is, if you have two positive factors $f_{1}, f_{2}$ such that $\frac{d}{4} = f_{1}f_{2}$ and $f_{1}-f_{2} = b$, 
then the only solution will be $f_{1} = \frac{a + b}{2}$, $f_{2}=\frac{a - b}{2}$ .
The sum of these factors will be $\frac{a + b}{2} + \frac{a - b}{2} = a$.

Edit: proof of the uniqueness of the factoring:
Theorem: 
Let $a$ $b$, be integers such that $a^2 - b^2$ is positive.
Let $f_{1}$, $f_{2}$ be positive integers such that $f_{1}f_{2} = \frac{a^2-b^2}{4}$ and $f_{1}-f_{2} = b$. 
Then $f_{1} = \frac{a+b}{2}$ and $f_{2}= \frac{a-b}{2}$.
Proof:
$\frac{a^2-b^2}{4} = f_{1} f_{2} =  f_{1}(f_{1} - b)\;\Rightarrow$
$\Rightarrow a^2-b^2 = 2f_{1}(2f_{1} - 2b)$
We can group the terms in the right-hand side:
$a^2-b^2 = (2f_{1} - b)^2 - b^2\Rightarrow$
$\Rightarrow a^2 =  (2f_{1} - b)^2\Rightarrow$
$\Rightarrow  2f_{1} -b = a$   or $2f_{1} -b = -a$.
Since $f_{1}$ must be positive, we get only $2f_{1} -b = a$ as a valid solution.
Therefore $f_{1} = \frac{a+b}{2}$ and $f_{2} = \frac{a-b}{2}$.

This makes a lot of sense when written in algebra,
Step 1: Take $~a^2 - b^2$
Step 2: Then $~\frac{a^2 - b^2}{4}$
Step 3: Find some $c$ such that $\frac{a^2 - b^2}{4} = c(c+b)$
Rearranging, $~a^2 = 4c^2 + 4bc + b^2$
$a^2 = (2c+b)^2$
$a = 2c+b$
In Step 4, the sum of the factors is $~c+(c+b) = 2c+b$, which is what was found to be $a$ in the last step, which is why your algorithm works. Nice :)
